# How to concatenate an array of number into one number

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation

I'm trying to take an array of any length of ints, and concatenate it into a single number without adding it up. For instance, if I have an array that goes as follows

```
[ 1, 7, 12, 16, 3, 8]
```

I want to have a variable that will equal `17121638`, not equal `47`.

I'm supposed to take a input of string and change it into an int without using `Interger.parseInt()` on the whole input itself.

This is my current attempt:

```
public static String toNum(String input) {
    String [] charArray = new String [input.length()];
    int [] parsedInput = new int [input.length()];
    for(int i; i < input.length(); i++){
        charArray[i] = input.substring(i);          
    }
    for(int c; c < charArray.length; c++){
        parsedInput[c] = Integer.parseInt(charArray[c]);            
    }
```

Comment: Are you having problems putting the ints into a String, or are you having problems parsing the String without using the Integer.parseInt() method?

Comment: I can interchange strings and ints just fine without parsing, its just getting the numbers to concatenate without actually adding the numbers up that's the problem. say if I want to crate a variable that concatenates the numbers 1, 4, and 16 I want that variable to be 1416, I don't want the variable to be 21. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[] nums = { 1, 7, 12, 16, 3, 8 };

StringBuilder strBigNum = new StringBuilder();
for (int n : nums)
    strBigNum.append(n);

long bigNum = 0;
long factor = 1;
for (int i = strBigNum.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    bigNum += Character.digit(strBigNum.charAt(i), 10) * factor;
    factor *= 10;
}
```

Now the `bigNum` variable contains the value `17121638`; in this case it was easier to work with strings. Be careful, if the input array is too big (or the numbers are too big) the resulting value won't fit in a `long`.

Comment: 1. `bigNum` is a `long` but `factor` is an `int`, which means your algorithm stops working way sooner than it should. 2. I always cringe when I see `+=` being applied to a `String`, especially in a loop, since it's a Schlemiel the Painter problem, and consider `StringBuilder` a much better fit for that (since it also implements `CharSequence` and thus has a `charAt` method also).

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young fixed `factor`'s type (that was a bug). Using `StringBuilder` here ... well, that's the right way to do it, but for a toy example I believe it's clearer with `+=`. I guess OP is just learning the basics

Answer (score 1):

Try to think about how the index of the left most number relates to it's power of 10 in the final number that you're trying to achieve. For example: having an array of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` should produce the integer `1234`. How does the base 10 power of 1000 relate to the length of the array and the index of `1`?

I phrase this as a question because I get the sense that this is a homework problem for school .

Answer (score 1):

Variant of Óscar López's solution that doesn't use any parsing (as the question requested):

```
public class BigNum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {1, 7, 12, 16, 3, 8};
        System.out.println(concatNums(nums));
    }

    public static long concatNums(int[] nums) {
        long result = 0;
        long multiplier = 1;
        for (int i = nums.length; i > 0; --i) {
            int num = nums[i - 1];
            while (num != 0) {
                result += multiplier * (num % 10);
                num /= 10;
                multiplier *= 10;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This won't work correctly if the array contains a 0. If that's important, let me know and I'll tweak the algorithm to accommodate it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the numbers together by the join method - that will give you a string and then convert it into a number by the Number function. 
you can simply run:

```
    var arr = [ 1, 7, 12, 16, 3, 8];
    var num = arr.join('');
    Number(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to return an int -- not a String!

Second -- technically -- you could use Integer.valueOf(s); which returns an Integer object with the exact value that .parseInt() would've returned... though I suspect that this would be considered "cheating."

Thirdly, I think this will help you along your way: http://nadeausoftware.com/node/97

Particularly the section titled:

> ### Parsing an integer from a string with custom code

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder to append each int num from numbers (int[]).

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for (int num : numbers) {
    sb.append(num);
 }

 return sb.toString();
```

Comment: That won't help the OP, since what do you do with the `StringBuilder` after you're done? Remember you're not allowed to use `parseInt`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

one line solution

```
String str = Arrays.toString(a).replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's another approach. Although this is similar to another answer, this one can handle some zeros. Just math, no use of Integer.parseInt:

```
public static int intsToInt(int[] input) {
    int total = 0;
    int multiplier = 1;

    for (int i=input.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (input[i] == 0) {
            multiplier *= Math.pow(10, String.valueOf(input[i]).length());
        }

        else {
            total += input[i]*multiplier;
            multiplier *= Math.pow(10, String.valueOf(input[i]).length());
        }
    }

    return total;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] ints = {1, 7, 12, 0, 16, 3, 8};
    out.println(digitsToInt(ints));
    out.println(intsToInt(ints));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation. Correct if it's wrong please (I'm a beginner).

```
int concatArray(int[] array){
    int sum = 0;
    int len = array.length-1;

    for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++){
        sum += (Math.pow(10, len) * array[i]);
        len--;
    }

    return sum;
}
```